# How To Avoid Looping Trigger Calls In PostgreSQL 9.2.1

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis, plpgsql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE field_data.soil_samples (
 pgid SERIAL NOT NULL,
 sample_id text,
 project_id text,
 utm_zone integer,
 utm_easting integer,
 utm_northing integer,
 wgs84_longitude double precision,
 wgs84_latitude double precision,
 yt_albers_geom geometry(Point,3578),
 CONSTRAINT soil_samples_pk PRIMARY KEY (pgid)
)
```

The PostGIS 2.0 geometry in `yt_albers_geom` is created using a trigger which fires on INSERTS against this table. If the record being inserted satisfies one of the following conditions, the geometry is generated:

1. Both `wgs84_latitude` and `wgs84_longitude` fields are not null
2. Each of `utm_zone`, `utm_easting`, and `utm_northing` are not null

Now, I am confused about how to do updates which achieve the following:

1. When an update is done to `utm_zone`, `utm_easting`, or `utm_northing`, then `wgs_84_latitude`, `wgs84_longitude`, and `yt_albers_geom` are updated by a trigger
2. When an update is done to `wgs84_latitude` or `wgs84_longitude`, then all the `utm_` fields are updated, as well as `yt_albers_geom`.
3. When an update is done to `yt_albers_geom`, all of the coordinate fields are updated.

It seems that any of these triggers would cause an infinite loop of trigger firing, correct?

Comment: Very nice, clear question! It's not that common that a question just has everything that's needed. Made me put in some effort.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with **standard triggers** `BEFORE UPDATE OF ... ON ...`.
[The manual on `CREATE TRIGGER` informs:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtrigger.html)

> The trigger will only fire if at least one of the listed columns is
>   mentioned as a target of the UPDATE command.

And further down:

> A column-specific trigger (one defined using the UPDATE OF column_name
>   syntax) will fire when any of its columns are listed as targets in the
>   UPDATE command's SET list. It is possible for a column's value to
>   change even when the trigger is not fired, because **changes made to the
>   row's contents by BEFORE UPDATE triggers are not considered.**

Bold emphasis mine. So no infinite loops, because the the updates inside the trigger do not invoke another trigger.

### Test case

Create test table (simplified, without irrelevant rows):

```sql
CREATE TABLE soil_samples (
  pgid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY

 ,utm_zone integer
 ,utm_easting integer
 ,utm_northing integer

 ,wgs84_longitude double precision
 ,wgs84_latitude double precision

 ,yt_albers_geom double precision
);
```

#### Dummy trigger for your first requirement:

> When an update is done to `utm_zone`, `utm_easting`, or `utm_northing`, then
>   `wgs_84_latitude`, `wgs84_longitude`, and `yt_albers_geom` are updated by a trigger.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_upbef_utm()  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.wgs84_latitude  := NEW.wgs84_latitude + 10;
   NEW.wgs84_longitude := NEW.wgs84_longitude + 10;
   NEW.yt_albers_geom  := NEW.yt_albers_geom + 10;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER upbef_utm
BEFORE UPDATE OF utm_zone, utm_easting, utm_northing ON soil_samples
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.utm_zone     IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.utm_zone    OR
      NEW.utm_easting  IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.utm_easting OR
      NEW.utm_northing IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.utm_northing)  -- optional
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_upbef_utm();
```

The `WHEN` clause is optional. Prevents the trigger from firing when no value has actually changed.

#### Dummy trigger for your second requirement:

> When an update is done to `wgs84_latitude` or `wgs84_longitude`, then all
>   the u`tm_` fields are updated, as well as `yt_albers_geom`.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_upbef_wgs84()  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW.utm_zone       := NEW.utm_zone + 100;
   NEW.utm_easting    := NEW.utm_easting + 100;
   NEW.utm_northing   := NEW.utm_northing + 100;
   NEW.yt_albers_geom := NEW.yt_albers_geom + 100;

   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER upbef_wgs84
 BEFORE UPDATE OF wgs84_latitude, wgs84_longitude ON soil_samples
 FOR EACH ROW
 WHEN (NEW.wgs84_latitude  IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.wgs84_latitude OR
       NEW.wgs84_longitude IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.wgs84_longitude)  -- optional
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_upbef_wgs84();
```

Trigger for **third requirement along these lines ...**

#### Test

```sql
INSERT INTO soil_samples VALUES (1, 1,1,1, 2,2, 3) RETURNING *;
```

Trigger `upbef_utm`: empty update, nothing happens:

```sql
UPDATE soil_samples SET utm_zone = 1 RETURNING *;
```

Update with actual change: The second trigger `upbef_wgs84` will not fire on `UPDATE OF utm_zone`!

```sql
UPDATE soil_samples SET utm_zone = 0 RETURNING *;
```

Trigger `upbef_wgs84`:

```sql
UPDATE soil_samples SET wgs84_latitude = 0 RETURNING *;
```

[**-> SQLfiddle demo.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dac29/1)

Comment: This answer is more than I could have hoped for!  Testing on my machine works as you describe... modifications made in a BEFORE UPDATE do not themselves fire triggers on the affected columns.  Thank you, thank you for the help.

Comment: Also, can you tell me if it is quicker to be doing the IS DISTINCT FROM evaluation in the trigger rather than in the trigger function?  IE: if I am testing a number of conditions, is it better to test each individually in their own trigger, and then to call a particular trigger function associated with the result of that evaluation, or should I write one trigger calling a single trigger function which contains a bunch of IF...ELSIF statements?  Thanks again for the expertise!

Comment: @Joebocop: That's the reason I added the `WHEN` condition to the trigger: it is generally faster. The reason is rather obvious: a simple expression is much cheaper to evaluate than calling a separate function for the job. You have to weigh higher maintenance cost against a small gain in performance before you start splitting things up. If you end up calling multiple triggers instead of one, then you are probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Further to your accepted solution, what is the expected outcome if an UPDATE statement is executed which updates wgs84_latitude, wgs84_longitude, and also yt_albers_geom?  Do both triggers fire in alphabetical order?

Comment: @Joebocop: Yes, triggers on the same event fire in alphabetical order.