# Postgresql easy update stack limit reached error

Tags: sql, psql, database-trigger

I have  a super simple table

id, entries, max_capacity, factor
So we have ex 500 max capacity and 250 entries and it should be 50 (50% full) easy right?
Problem is when I update the entries I want the factor to auto update as well, so I have done the function:

```
create function myUp() returns trigger as $$
begin
update myTable
set factor=round(100*(entries/max_capacity),0);
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

and the trigger

```
create trigger myUp 
after insert or update on myTable
for each row
execute procedure myUp();
```

and I get a new trigger function and running an update example

```
update myTable
set entries=500
where id=1;
```

Where I update the entries on one of the rows and I get the ERROR stack depth limit exceeded CONTEXT update myTable....

Why do I get this? Do I have to set the entries for all of the rows for it to work? I have no clue why it is not working. I want the after because I cant calculate the value before I inserted the new entries values.

Comment: An update trigger is updating the same table.  Seems like a hall of mirrors.  The updates will go on *ad infinitum*.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13663926/how-to-avoid-looping-trigger-calls-in-postgresql-9-2-1